# Parse key- value as weighted bubble output

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I want to show key/value pairs (of social relationship data count) in bubble using D3.js or something similar.
Here goes my output from REST client:

```
{"data":{"sister":3,"General":130,"mother":3,"guest":1,"brother":10,"general":1,"father":4},"messages":[]}
```

And here goes the Jquery code for the same. I am getting keys in 'arr' and values in 'values' in the following code. All I need to output the data in visual form as bubble as per weight, example, 'General' count is 130, so it should have biggest bubble. like that.

```
    $(document).on("click", "#socialGraph", function(){
        var id="4501905311187190264";

$.ajax({
        url: "/getSocialGraph/"+id,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){

            var arr=Object.keys(data.data);
            var value=[];
            for(var i in arr){
                value.push(data.data[arr[i]]);
            }
```

Comment: This will help http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

Comment: If I were you I will go for just canvas or css.